# JAR included in a project and while i am creating WAR file JAR packages are missing(SPRING BOOT)

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I added JAR dependency in pom.xml. While i am creating WAR file of the particular project i am getting an error that few packages do not exist. But, when i am manually exporting the JAR file and replacing in local repository, project is executing.

WAR (TARGET)pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    org
    Target
    1.0
    war
    
        1.8
    
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.0.4.RELEASE
    
    
            
            org.source
            source
            1.0
         
        
            org.springframework.boot
            spring-boot-starter-web
            
                
                    org.springframework.boot
                    spring-boot-starter-logging

```
    <!-- JSTL tag lib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1206-jdbc42</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.4</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>1.9</version> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.ehcache-spring-annotations</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-spring-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Tomcat for JSP rendering -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xalan/xalan -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xalan</groupId>
        <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-csv</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context-support -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration> 
                <classifier>exec</classifier> 
                </configuration> 
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question misses some info. Could you show us the pom.xml/gradle file?

Comment: "I added JAR dependency in pom.xml." how did you add it? "While i am creating WAR file" how are you creating it? Add the relevant sections of your pom.xml to the question.

Comment: i added pom.xml of target project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write a proper build script in your pom.xml file. A proper script makes the necessary directories and copies the right files for you.

Comment: i added pom.xml. can you please review and let me know the mistake i have done.

Comment: add **maven-war-plugin** to your pom.xml and then just simply call ''mvn compile war:war'' and you get your war file